# Count duplicate rows in a csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I imagine this is an easy one for a decent Python dev - Im still learning! Given a csv with duplicate emails I would like to iterate and write out the count of duplicate emails eg:

**infile.csv**

```
COLUMN 0
some@email.com
some@email.com
another@address.com
example@email.com
```

**outfile.csv**

```
COLUMN 0                 COLUMN 1
some@email.com           2
another@address.com      1
example@email.com        1
```

So far I can remove duplicates with

```
import csv

f = csv.reader(open('infile.csv','rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv','wb'))
emails = set()


for row in f:
    if row[0] not in emails:
        writer.writerow(row)
        emails.add( row[0] )
```

but I am having trouble writing the count to a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `defaultdict` which *is* in Python2.6

```
from collections import defaultdict

# count all the emails before we write anything out
emails = defaultdict(int)
for row in f:
    emails[row[0]] += 1

# now write the file
for row in email.items():
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Yes -- this is the better answer for an OLDER Python. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try a [counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It is designed for such use:

```
from collections import Counter

emails=Counter()
for row in f:
    emails+=Counter([row[0]])
```

Prints:

```
Counter({'some@email.com': 2, 'another@address.com': 1, 'example@email.com': 1, 'COLUMN 0': 1})
```

It is easy to get any other data structure  from a counter:

```
print set(emails.elements())
# set(['another@address.com', 'COLUMN 0', 'example@email.com', 'some@email.com'])
```

Note that I did not skip the header or write out the csv -- it is easy to do.

Comment: Make sure to note that Counter is only available on python 2.7+

Comment: @rebelbass -- if you're using 2.6, you can also pretty easily use a `defaultdict` for this.  (`d = collections.defaultdict(int)` and `d[key] += 1` ...)

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.6 you could try something like a pigeonhole sort: 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort

It's actually kinda made for this exact kind of problem.

For actual setup, use a dictionary to hold the data and then iterate over it instead of trying to write the info out as you go.